# My buttons in android are not working

Tags: java, android

This is how i added buttons in java file

```
btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
btnDelete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
btnModify=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnModify);
btnView=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnView);
btnViewAll=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewAll);
btnShowInfo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowInfo);
```

Comment: what is not working?why do u think it's not working ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you grab a reference to the button, you need to set an onClickListener to the button.  For example:

```
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // do something after the add button is clicked
        }
    });
```

Additionally, make sure the android:clickable="true" flag is included in your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems to be fine, If you mean why your buttons aren't responding to touch, you need to set an onClickListener to each button, or add an onClick attribute your xml layout file, check this for more details
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#RespondToButton